# Calculate the percentage In Power BI

Tags: powerbi-desktop

| Category | Location | Sum of Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Application | HYBRID | 123 |
| Application | PrivateCloud | 345 |
| Application | PublicCloud | 7534 |
| Application | UNKNOWN | 2347 |
| Total | 10,349 |  |

This is Applications table. I need you to find Public Cloud percentage in total Applications in Power BI.

| Category | Location | Sum of Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Application | HYBRID | 123 |
| Application | PrivateCloud | 345 |
| Application | PublicCloud | 7534 |
| Application | UNKNOWN | 2347 |
| Total | 10,349 |  |

This is Applications table. I need you to find Public Cloud percentage in total Applications in Power BI.
I need DAX query